# In the problem of best linear predictor, why is $E(XX')$ positive definite equivalent to $E(XX')$ being invertible?

Tags: regression, probability, linear-model, predictor, mse

I came across the following statement in a textbook when discussing the classic best linear predictor problem in statistics. It says $E[XX']$ being positive definite is equivalent to it being invertible. I'm wondering why it is the case here because in general an invertible matrix is not necessarily positive definite. (Positive definiteness and nonsingularity makes no difference in the calculation of the best linear predictor coefficient $E[XX']^{-1}E[XY]$, but it does make a difference for arguing that the best linear predictor coefficient achieves the global minimum of the objective function.) Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There is a straightforward demonstration that pd implies invertibility.  Invertibility of an endomorphism (which is what any square matrix represents) is equivalent to being *injective:* that is, $Q$ is invertible if and only if $Qx=Qy$ implies $x=y.$ Let $x$ and $y$ be vectors for which $Qx=Qy.$  Then $$(x-y)^\prime Q(x-y) = (x-y)^\prime(Qx-Qy)=(x-y)^\prime(0) = 0.$$  When $Q$ is positive-definite that implies $x-y=0,$ whence $x=y$ *QED.*

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot! This is quite elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because $E[XX']$ is inherently positive semi-definite, as for any non-random $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
\begin{align}
z'E[XX']z = E[z'XX'z] = E[(X'z)'(X'z)] \geq 0. 
\end{align}

Now the result follows from the fact that a positive semi-definite matrix that is invertible is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.

Comment: Another question: is any invertible psd matrix also pd, or only invertible symmetric psd matrix is pd?